# Azure Functions Runtime Unreachable

Tags: azure, docker, azure-functions, containers

Whenever I deploy docker image and update tag in Deployment Center of Azure Function, I faced "Azure Functions Runtime Unreachable". I have followed this article "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-recover-storage-account" but it did not solved this as I have already defined application settings.
[image]

What could be the issue and how can I solve this?

Comment: Go to  Storage account, in side the Fileshare, check if a file share has been created or not with the same name of Azure function. If not then that's the root cause. Not sure how you are creating the Azure function . is it manual or through ARM?

Comment: If its using ARM, then storage need to get created first, then create the function app, then pass the Storage connection string in the AzureWebjobStorage varible in the appsetting. When function will be created, then FunctionApp will create the Required file share. & all required files will be store for azure runtime inside that.

Comment: storage account is already created and its connection string saved to appsettings. whenever I change Tag of docker image in deployment center and save it then this error occurs.

Comment: Could you please refer this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=in-process%2Cbash%2Cazure-cli&pivots=programming-language-python#create-and-configure-a-function-app-on-azure-with-the-image) , and confirm once as mentioned "*If you are using a custom container registry then the deployment-container-image-name parameter will refer to the registry URL*" also make sure to restart your function app .